# Calculate sum with binomial coefficients: $\sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{1}{k+1} \binom nk x^{k+1}$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, summation, binomial-coefficients, factorial

I need help with finding the sum of $\sum \limits_{k=0}^{n} \frac{1}{k+1}{n\choose k}x^{k+1}$

Comment: Call it $f(x)$, differentiate. $f'(x)$ should look familiar. Integrate.

Comment: @DanielFischer: .. and remember to add a constant, in casu 1.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hint

$$\sum \limits_{k=0}^{n} \frac{1}{k+1}{n\choose k}x^{k+1}=\int_0^x \sum \limits_{k=0}^{n} {n\choose k}t^{k}dt=\int_0^x(1+t)^ndt$$

Can you take it from here?